# Searching for value in nested php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this, that could have any number of "domain" arrays. I've removed unnecessary keys in this example.

```
Array
(
    [result] => success
    [clientid] => 7
    [numreturned] => 2
    [domains] => Array
        (
            [domain] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domainname] => example.net
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [domainname] => example.com
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to figure out how to check this array to see if it contains a domain name.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if(arrayContains("example.com")){
$success = true;
}
```

I have tried a number of solutions I found on SO, but they don't appear to be working. One example I found used array_key_exists, which is kind of the opposite of what I need.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at `array_search()`? - http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-search.php#91365

Comment: I tried the code you linked to in that comment, and it worked. If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it, as you were the first to answer, and your solution worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll post an answer as soon as I get back to my PC.

Comment: @SherwinFlight If by any chance you used the code I posted. I wanted to let you know I've edited my answer. The previous answer was buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to help you out:

```
<?php
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

This was found in one of the comments in the PHP doc about [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-search.php#91365).

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    "result" => "success",
    "clientid" => 7,
    "numreturned" => 2,
    "domains" => array(
            "domain" => array(
                    0 => array(
                            "domainname" => "somedomain.com",
                            3 => array(
                                "domainname" => "searchdomanin.com",

                                ),
                        ),

                    1 => array(
                            "domainname" => "extwam",
                        ),

                )

        )

);

$succes = FALSE;
$search = 'searchdomanin.com';

array_walk_recursive($array, function($key, $value) use(&$success, &$search){ 
    if($key === $search){
       $success = TRUE;
    }
},
[&$key ,&$val]);

if($success){
    echo 'FOUND';
}
```

Works with whatever dimension array you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$domains = $arr['domains'];
foreach($domains AS $domain)
{
   foreach($domain AS $internal_arr)
   {
      if($internal_arr['domainname'] == 'example.net')
      {
        $success = true;
      }
   }
}
```